# How to add dynamic actionlink in foreach in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

Am trying to add dynamic actionlink like below but am unable to pass the exact value please help me.

```
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.SubmenuItems)
{
     <div style="padding:10px;" class="col-md-12">
     <a href="@Url.Action("+@item.Action+","+@item.Controller+")" 
     style="font-weight:bold;color:crimson">@item.Name  >></a>
     </div>  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, you do not need to use `+` sign which is for concatenation, as `Url.Action` method only needs `string` type parameters for the overload you are using, do like:

```
<a href="@Url.Action(item.Action,item.Controller)"
```

This would work fine if the `Action` and `Controller` property are of type `string`, assuming that they are `string` as you were doing concatenation.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Hmm maybe you are right but when am pass like this am getting this error. "'IUrlHelper' has no applicable method named 'Action' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax."

Comment: but i have got when i pass like this <a <a href="@Url.Action((string)item.Action,(string)item.Controller)". Thank you.